# Tell me the ideal selling price to get back a specified number

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If I am buying something at xxx,
what is the price to sell it if I want a profit of $2.50 after minus-ing  0.63% (broker fee) from the selling price?

I need to make this into an excel formula, but this is the first step... if you know the excel formula that would be a great help as well!

Thanks!

Comment: *To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far*. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people tend to be more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself.

Comment: Ok! Thanks for the advise, this is my first question here! My thoughts so far are: buying price+$2.50+broker fee... but that is wrong so am still trying to work it out in my head. Was never good at math... but I'm trying to learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
\mathsf{profit}&=(\mathsf{selling\;price}) - (\mathsf{broker\;fee})-(\mathsf{price\;you\;bought\;it\;for})\\
\end{align*}$$
So you want to solve
$$\begin{align*}
2.50&=(\mathsf{selling\;price}) - (0.63\%\mathsf{\;of\;selling\;price})-(\mathsf{price\;you\;bought\;it\;for})\\\\
2.50&=(\mathsf{selling\;price})-(0.0063)(\mathsf{selling\;price})-(\mathsf{price\;you\;bought\;it\;for})\\\\
2.50&=(0.9937)(\mathsf{selling\;price})-(\mathsf{price\;you\;bought\;it\;for})\\\\
(0.9937)(\mathsf{selling\;price})&=2.50+(\mathsf{price\;you\;bought\;it\;for})\\\\
(\mathsf{selling\;price})&=\frac{2.50+(\mathsf{price\;you\;bought\;it\;for})}{0.9937}\\\\
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Boy, you can't wait for that `\textsf` command to be added, eh? :-)

Comment: Haha yeah, I'm liking the look of the `\sf` font for purposes like this :)

Comment: For posts like this you should use `\newcommand{\tsf}[1]{\mathsf{\text{#1}}}` and then use `\tsf` more freely (without the spacing commands all the time).

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow, perhaps I explained it wrong: I dont have the selling price as yet, I only have the buying price and the broker fee...I need to find out the selling price.

Comment: For example if I bought it at  100, whats the price to sell it at if I need to make $2.50 in profit?

Comment: @Ryan: Use the formula that my answer concludes with.
$$(\mathsf{selling\;price})=\frac{2.50+100}{0.9937}\approx 103.15$$

Comment: Sorry, like I said, I suck at math! Can you tell me how you got that 0.9937?

Comment: @Ryan: $0.9937$ is $1-0.0063$. Where did $0.0063$ come from? That is what $0.63\%$ is. Remember, $p\%$ of $x$ means
$$\frac{p}{100}\cdot x$$
so $0.63\%$ of the selling price is
$$\frac{0.63}{100}\cdot (\mathsf{selling\;price})=(0.0063)(\mathsf{selling\;price}).$$
Now, you use the distributive property to combine terms:
$$ax-bx=(a-b)x$$
so
$$(\mathsf{selling\;price})- (0.0063)(\mathsf{selling\;price})=(0.9937)(\mathsf{selling\; price})$$

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate it! Have a good day!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!